# How do I run a command in a list of directories using bash?

Tags: macos, bash, loops

I need to run some commands in OS X User directories, apart from "Shared" and our local admin account.
So far, I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
userFolders=$(find /Users/ -type d -depth 1 | sed -e 's/\/\//\//g' | egrep -v "support|Shared")
for PERSON in "$userFolders"; do
    mkdir $PERSON/Desktop/flagFolderForLoop
done
```

Running the above as root, I get

```
mkdir: /Users/mactest1: File exists
```

Where might I be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the quotes around `"$userFolders"` so that your loop iterates over each person correctly.

The following example illustrates the difference between quoting and not quoting:

**With quotes:**

```
for i in "a b c"
do
    echo "Param: $i"
done
```

prints *only one* parameter:

```
Param: a b c
```

**Without quotes:**

```
for i in a b c
do
    echo "Param: $i"
done
```

prints each parameter:

```
Param: a
Param: b
Param: c
```

Also, you can tell `find` to exclude certain directories, like this:

```
for PERSON in $(find /Users/ -type d -depth 1 ! -name support ! -name Shared)
do
    mkdir "$PERSON"/Desktop/flagFolderForLoop
done
```

Comment: You could use `exec` option of `find` as well I guess... something on these lines maybe :`find /Users/ -type d -depth 1 ! -name support ! -name Shared -exec mkdir {}/Desktop/flagFolderForLoop \;` to get rid of the `for` loop. Btw on Ubuntu system I use, `find` has no option called `depth` instead it has `maxdepth`, not sure about OSX though

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `find` you can use `dscl` to list (regular, standard) `/Users` on Mac OS X.

```
dscl . -list  /Users NFSHomeDirectory

# list name of users
dscl . -list /Users NFSHomeDirectory | 
   awk '/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+\/Users\//{print $1}'

# list home directories of users
dscl . -list /Users NFSHomeDirectory | 
   awk '/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+\/Users\//{$1=""; sub(/^ */,""); print $0}'
```